# Not able to select a row in my ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm not able to select a row in my list Item

Here is my code

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="250">
 <ListView x:Name="ListVendors" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
  <ListView.View>
   <GridView>
    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
     <Style><Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/></Style>
    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
    <GridViewColumn>
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition />
         <RowDefinition />
         <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Code}" Foreground="Gray" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding ContactNo}" Foreground="Gray" />
       </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn>
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Address, Converter={StaticResource addNewLineConv}}" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
       </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn>
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
       </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email"/>
  </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

How can I select a row in the ListView??

Comment: It works for me. In future, please provide complete sample, as it's not very convenient to generate classes when trying to reproduce the problem. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sorry @Athari i'll provide one next time. For me this is working but I can not select a row.

Comment: I've created a new WPF app and used this code: http://pastebin.com/GuwrYinu It does work. There's something else in your application which is the source of the problem (default ListView style?)

Comment: Would you mind checking my code once ?? http://pastebin.com/QGiSALjt

Comment: You haven't read http://sscce.org